# redux-form validation for reusable component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Hey I try to use reduxform validation and apply validation on component that is reusable within a form and called more than once.

but i end up with all of the comp bound to each other. not within their own context.

the comp:

```
export const fields = ['myField'];

const validate = values => {
    const errors = {};

    // just to see the error:
    errors.myField = 'error!! ';

    return errors;
};

class myField extends React.Component {

    render() {

        const {
            fields: { myField }
        } = this.props;


        return (
            <div className="myField">

                <input type="text" {...myField}  />
                {myField.touched && myField.error && <span>{myField.error}</span>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

myField.propTypes = {
    fields: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

myField = reduxForm({
        form: 'myform',
        fields: fields,
        destroyOnUnmount: false,
        validate
    }
)(myField);
```

i tried to use '[]' within the name but i end up with X arrays of X components. so '[]' seems it should be used for lists but not new instances of the same component.

```
export const fields = ['myField'];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `reduxForm()` decorator should decorate *the whole form*, not an individual input. You need something more like this (component classes should be capitalized):

```
// validate.js
const validate = values => {
    const errors = {};

    // just to see the error:
    errors.firstField = 'error!!';
    errors.secondField = 'error!!';

    return errors;
};

// ----------------

// MyField.js
class MyField extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { field } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="myField">
        <input type="text" {...myField}  />
        {myField.touched && myField.error && <span>{myField.error}</span>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
MyField.propTypes = {
  field: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

// ----------------

// MyForm.js
import MyField from './MyField';
import validate from './validate';

class MyForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      fields: { firstField, secondField }
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="myForm">
        <MyField field={firstField}/>
        <MyField field={secondField}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

MyForm.propTypes = {
  fields: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

MyForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'myform',
  fields: ['firstField', 'secondField'],
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
  validate
})(MyForm);
```

Comment: ```Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `validate` of type `object` supplied to `ReduxForm(ItemForm)`, expected `function`. Check the render method of `Connect(ReduxForm(ItemForm))`.
Uncaught TypeError: validate is not a function
```